# What the reason for AWS Health status becoming RED?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've deployed an application to AWS elastic beanstalk.

after start the application, it runs well. But after 5 minutes(I set health check every 5 min), it runs failed. I access the url but HTTP 503 error back.

From the event info, I only get the info that the health status from YELLOW TO GREEN.

But how can I get detailed info and what can I do about this error?

BTW: I don't understand that is this health status RED leads to application can't start up OR something else failed leads to application failed, then the health status becomes to RED?

Answer (score 2):

Elastic Load Balancing has a health check daemon that checks the path you've provided for a 200-range HTTP status.

If there is a problem with the application, or its not returning a 2xx status code, or if you've misconfigured the health check URL, the status will go RED.

Two things you can do to see what's going on:

1. Hit the hostname of an individual instance in your web browser — particularly the health check path. Are you seeing what you expected?
2. SSH into the instance and check the logs in `/var/log` and `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/var/log`. Are there any errors that you can find?

Without knowing more about your application, stack or container type, that's the best I can do.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'm confused why before system starts health check, the application runs well. Once health check start, it turns the status from GREEN TO YELLOW then RED.

Comment: /var/log error log file displays: Digest:generating secret for digest authentication...\nDigest:done\n Apache/2.2.22 Dav/2 PHP/5.3.14 configured -- resuming normal operations\n

Comment: `sudo -i` will elevate you to root.